# Download's amount in google play

Tags: download, google-play

Today I saw that amount of downloads in my app on google play decreased to 100. But yesterday was few thousands. In developer console everything is fine and I see correct total installs. But in  Google Play as a user: 100 downloads. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Happened to me too! My app had 500 000 downloads and now it shows 100 000 (active are 180 000). They probably changed the formula :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem yesterday. Today is all fine. 
It was probably some bug of google play's side.
Other suggestion is that they are experimenting new formulas for showing the installs (because too many apps have a millions of total downloads, but only few thosand active)

Refresh google play and clear cache. Should be fine for you too